# Primality radii in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Under Goldbach conjecture, say a positive integer  $ r $ is a primality radius of a large enough composite integer  $ n $ if and only if both  $ n-r $ and  $ n+r $ are prime. Let for given  $ n $ the quantity  $ N_{2} $ to be the number of primality radii of  $ n $ and  $ k $ the greatest positive integer not exceeding  $ \sqrt{N_2} $ (the assumption of GC entails this number always exists).

Can one always find a  $ k $-term sequence of primality radii of  $ n $ in arithmetic progression with minimal positive common difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, even without the minimal positive common difference condition.

The first counterexample is $n=81$, which has $10$ primality radii that contain no arithmetic progression of length $3$:
$$\{2,8,20,22,28,50,58,68,70,76\}$$

More generally, we can note that if the radii are in AP, then so are the equivalent $n-r$ values. That is, we are also finding primes in AP. The number of radii grows relatively quickly and the required $k$ soon exceeds the longest known prime APs. The current record prime AP has length $26$, but:

$n=12285, N_2=690, k=26$
$n=13650, N_2=738, k=27$

OEIS, number of radii: http://oeis.org/A002375
Reference for record prime APs: http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for this insightful answer.